# Error while posting data in spring boot using @RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I keep getting this error while writing a spring boot application using REST API.

> {
>       "status": 415,
>       "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
>       "message": "Content type 'text/plain' not supported" }

How do I get rid of the error?

My Post Request code is as follows, in my

```
StudentController.java,

@RequestMapping(value = "/students/{studentId}/courses", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = {"application/json"})

public ResponseEntity<Void> registerStudentForCourse(@PathVariable String studentId, @RequestBody course newCourse) 
{

        course course1 = studentService.addCourse(studentId, newCourse);
        if (course1 == null)
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(course1.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

And my postman input for the requestBody is as follows, to add a new course to student . The code is in json

```
{
 "name":"Microservices",
 "description"="10 Steps",
 "steps":
 [
    "Learn How to Break Things up ",
    "Automate the hell out of everything ",
    "Have fun"
 ]
}
```

`My addcourse()` method is as follows :

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
public course addCourse(String studentId, course cour)
{
    Student student = retrieveStudent(studentId);
    if(student==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    String randomId = new BigInteger(130,random).toString(32);
    cour.setId(randomId);
    student.getCourses().add(cour);
    return cour;
}
```

Comment: The exception tells you all... You are sending plain text, not JSON (according to the content-type). So fix your postman request.

Comment: You also have magic strings (instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`), and everything besides `@PostMapping("/students/{studentId}/courses")` is just distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint only accepts `application/json` but you send `text/plain`.

Just add `content-type: application/json` to your HTTP request header.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the line from :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students/{studentId}/courses", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = {"application/json"})
```

To :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students/{studentId}/courses", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
```